# Invalidate UserControl Error in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I created an UserControl and everything works great except for the properties. The problem is I lost all the Design Property in my UserControl.. to be more clear, i made a screenshot.

**This is my UserControl**

[image]

**..and a ToolStrip sample**

[image]

this is my sample code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;

namespace _Sample__User_Control
{

  [Designer("Sytem.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner,System.Design", typeof(IDesigner))]
  public partial class ClientsCollectionListBox : UserControl
  {
    public ClientsCollectionListBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [Browsable(true)]
    [DefaultValue("Hello")]
    public string MyString { get; set; }
  }
}
```

my User Control doesn't have the Design Property. Upon dragging the User Control to my form, there's still the Design Property but upon running or adding another instance to this control, i lost the display. Any help for this problem would be appreciated. Do i need to Invalidate on load?

**SOLUTION:**

Spelling error.. sorry.. please close this thread..

```
 [Designer("Sytem.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner,System.Design", typeof(IDesigner))]

 [Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner,System.Design", typeof(IDesigner))]
```

Comment: Up for this question.. maybe you got an idea.. i will be happy if you contribute some. :)

Comment: I created a sample User Control based on the code you posted, added two instances of it to the form and I can see `Design` properties category for each of them. I'm not sure, but maybe the issue is somewhere in the control or its properties not handling multiple instances correctly.